# Complex CouchDb View

Tags: view, couchdb, reduce

I have the following documents in a database:

```
{
  id: 1,
  text: 'Hello I had a big grannysmith apple today and a big pear'
},
{
  id: 2,
  text: 'Hello I had a big apple today only'
},
{
  id: 3,
  text: 'Hello I had a big apple today, a big pear yesterday and a big orange today'
}
```

My view needs to return an aggregated count of specific keywords in the text, but the keywords need to be 'loose' on how they found. My view should return something like this:

```
{
  'grannysmith apple' : 3,
  'pear': 2,
  'orange': 1
}
```

As you can see I have counted **apples** 3 times even though the tag is for **'grannysmith apple'**, I still want to pick up any occurrences of **'apples'** as well.

Is this possible? Or should I be doing this before I insert into CouchDb? I'm using node.js to perform the saving - should I do it in node.js?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you always know your keywords up front?

Comment: Along the same lines as Dominic, do you know the synonyms you want to allow, so that you could compare to an array of synonyms or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [RegExp objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) as keywords and [aggregate with `group_level`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API).